# Error not sent to Sentry using pino-sentry-transport

Tags: javascript, pino

I try to send errors to sentry in the production environment:

```
import pino from 'pino';
const logger = pino(
    {
      level: 'error',
      formatters: {
        level: label => {
          return { level: label };
        },
      },
      transport: {
        target: 'pino-sentry-transport',
        options: {
          sentry: {
            dsn: 'xxxxx',
          },
        },
      },
      timestamp: () => `,"timestamp":"${new Date(Date.now()).toISOString()}"`,
    }
  );
```

I installed `pino-sentry-transport` and tried to log an error but it does not work. When I tried `pino-sentry` and used stream, all the level logs are sent to sentry without the error stack and context:

```
import pino from 'pino';
import { createWriteStream } from 'pino-sentry';

const logger = pino(
    {
      level: 'error',
      formatters: {
        level: label => {
          return { level: label };
        },
      },
      transport: {
        target: 'pino-sentry-transport',
        options: {
          sentry: {
            dsn: 'xxxxx',
          },
        },
      },
      timestamp: () => `,"timestamp":"${new Date(Date.now()).toISOString()}"`,
    },
createWriteStream({
    level: 'error',
    dsn: 'xxx',
    }),
  );
How can I fix that?
```

Answer (score 1):

The `minLevel` option for `pino-sentry-transport` enables this:

```js
{
  target: 'pino-sentry-transport',
  options: {
    sentry: {
      dsn: "sentry-url"
    },
    minLevel: 40 // Only errors & above should be sent to Sentry.
  },
  level: 'error' // it seems that when configuring a single transport, this can be omitted (and defaults to 'info'). When configuring multiple ones, it's required.
}
```

Reference: [pino-sentry-transport Usage](https://github.com/tomer-yechiel/pino-sentry-transport#usage)

[List of Numeric Log Levels in pinojs](https://github.com/pinojs/pino/blob/32b759d7baa91ae4baa581630f4563195deceee6/lib/levels.js#L13)

Answer (score 0):

you can use the pino-sentry package instead of `pino-sentry-transport`. The `pino-sentry` package provides a **stream** that sends logs to Sentry

```js
const pino = require('pino');
const pinoSentry = require('pino-sentry');

const logger = pino({
  level: 'error',
  formatters: {
    level: label => {
      return { level: label };
    },
  },
  timestamp: () => `,"timestamp":"${new Date(Date.now()).toISOString()}"`,
});

const stream = pinoSentry({
  dsn: 'xxx',
});

logger.pipe(stream);
```

you too can try creating separate logger instance just for error logging and configure it to use the pino-sentry-transport:

```
import pino from 'pino';
import pinoSentryTransport from 'pino-sentry-transport';
import * as Sentry from '@sentry/node';

Sentry.init({
  dsn: 'xxxxx',
});

const errorLogger = pino(
  {
    level: 'error',
    timestamp: () => `,"timestamp":"${new Date(Date.now()).toISOString()}"`,
  },
  pinoSentryTransport({ sentry: Sentry })
);

// Example error log
errorLogger.error(new Error('An error occurred!'));
```

Comment: I tried it but it send all the log levels to sentry even I set level to 'error'.